# How to listen for date input when using Vuetify 3 Datepicker in keyboard mode?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vuetify 3 and want to have a datepicker in keyboard mode. I started with [this playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVkDFPwzAQhf/KyVMr4WQoEhKkCCQWJMSCxIIZHOfSRHVsy7FTUNX/ztlpaTvZ5/vu+d772rPRq/LZuWKKyO5ZNSrfuwAjhuhAS7NZCxZGwR6FAegHZ32APXhs4QCttwMIRpOCPQiTCGXNGEBF79GEFxkQ1gleGNxBKhfL5ZFso1Ghtwasecdd7hGUziXsEzCLWY2FtpuFYJzDK3RyQqgRDSipNTbAuWBJMvPnb4tJ6pg+P2pm4iBMVc4GyQ4VAQenqZvNVROXzuVrLhpqcNerLfr5jfwbFwMfbIOUyhZ/ayt9I9h1mxQVdlY36In6cKj6tlfQWj/IALUcaWuyrS05oOCuhwP+BJp6kzVq2FgcoUN/QXV9g7xDSeKnp/u0j+bZMI1ehHAee4ou2ZnRzyP5H/yJK+ccylMQVXkREDvcsFWxKu5YOm+LFfv+A6KXvDM=)

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const currentDate = ref(new Date());

  function onNewDate(newDate) {
    console.log("-- I have been called --");
    currentDate.value = newDate;
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-date-picker
      input-mode="keyboard"
      input-placeholder="Specific format based on locale"
      input-text="Label goes here"
      hide-header
      :model-value="currentDate"
      @update:modelValue="onNewDate"
    />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I don't know how the `@update:modelValue` event works. The event won't trigger. How do I use this component in keyboard mode?

Comment: The reason the event doesn't trigger is because the component in keyboard mode doesn't update it's v-model value (you can see it not updating by putting `<div>{{ currentDate }}</div>` in your template).  Probably a bug that should be reported.  You should just use VTextField component instead.  It seems to be what VDatePicker renders as when in keyboard mode anyways.

Comment: There are some issues I think https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/18775

Comment: Indeed, they are removing it soon.  "keyboard mode was not supposed to still exist, it never worked properly" -- Vuetify dev.

Comment: I gave up trying to use `v-date-picker` (too buggy and still in labs mode anyway). I am now using  https://vue3datepicker.com instead